# DB connection pool in Qt

Tags: c++, multithreading, qt

I have Qt application which has `DatabaseService` singleton with only one `QSqlDatabase` instance, and many threads which should to use this instance of `QSqlDatabase`, mutex is locked when some thread uses instance of `QSqlDatabase`. But I understand that this isn't best pattern for this task.

**Should I use some kind of DB connection pool here or something like this? And how can I implement it in Qt?**

Please provide some examples.

---

**UPD:**

A class whose instance will **already** have its own thread, there will be multiple instances of this class:

.cpp:

```
//...

QFuture<QMap<QString, QString>> future = QtConcurrent::run(DatabaseService::executeQuery, sqlCommand);

future.waitForFinished();

//...
```

---

DatabaseService:

.h:

```
class DatabaseService
{
public:
    //...
    static QMap<QString, QString> executeQuery(QString command);

private:
    static QThreadStorage<QSqlDatabase> mDatabasePool;
    static QSqlDatabase getDatabase();

};
```

.cpp:

```
//...
QThreadStorage<QSqlDatabase> DatabaseService::mDatabasePool;

QSqlDatabase DatabaseService::getDatabase()
{
    if(DatabaseService::mDatabasePool.hasLocalData()) {
        return DatabaseService::mDatabasePool.localData();
    } else {
        auto database = QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QPSQL", QUuid::createUuid().toString());
        database.setHostName("hostName");
        database.setDatabaseName("databaseName");
        database.setUserName("user");
        database.setPassword("password");
        DatabaseService::mDatabasePool.setLocalData(database);
        return database;
    }
}

QMap<QString,QString> DatabaseService::executeQuery(QString command){

    QSqlQuery query (DatabaseService::getDatabase());
    query.exec(command);

    //...

    return result;
}

//...
```

---

**UPD 2:**

main.cpp:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);

    MyServer server;

    server.listen(QHostAddress::Any, 1234);

    return a.exec();
}
```

myserver.h:

```
class MyServer : public QTcpServer
{
    Q_OBJECT

    explicit MyServer(QObject *parent = 0);
    ~MyServer();

protected:
    void incomingConnection(qintptr socketDescriptor) Q_DECL_OVERRIDE;

signals:
    void stopAll();
};
```

myserver.cpp:

```
MyServer::MyServer(QObject *parent) : QTcpServer(parent)
{

}

MyServer::~MyServer(){
    emit stopAll();
}

void MyServer::incomingConnection(qintptr socketDescriptor){
    QThread* clientThread = new QThread;
    MyClient *client = new MyClient(socketDescriptor, this);

    client->moveToThread(clientThread);

    connect(clientThread, SIGNAL(started()), client, SLOT(process()));

    connect(client, SIGNAL(finished()), clientThread, SLOT(quit()));
    connect(this, SIGNAL(stopAll()), client, SLOT(stopFromServer()));
    connect(client, SIGNAL(finished()), client, SLOT(deleteLater()));
    connect(clientThread, SIGNAL(finished()), clientThread, SLOT(deleteLater()));

    clientThread->start();
}
```

myclient.h:

```
class MyClient : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit MyClient(int socketDescriptor, MyServer *server);
    ~MyClient();

private:
    QSslSocket* socket = NULL;

public slots:
    void process();
}
```

myclient.cpp:

```
void MyClient::process(){
    //typical connection things
    connect(this->socket, SIGNAL(encrypted()), this, SLOT(ready()));
}

void MyClient::ready(){
    connect(socket,SIGNAL(readyRead()),this, SLOT(newData()));
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have made a software also using database connection. I don't use QThread on my application but use QFuture and the thread will take from global thread pool (normaly the number of thread pool will be the number of the CPU thread).

And when accessing the database, each pool will has its own QSqlDatabase. I am using QThreadStorage as the storage of QSqlDatabase.

```
static QThreadStorage<QSqlDatabase> mDatabasePool;
....
QSqlDatabase Db::getDatabase()
{
    if(mDatabasePool.hasLocalData()) {
        return mDatabasePool.localData();
    } else {
        auto database = QSqlDatabase::addDatabase(SQLDRIVERNAME[DBTYPE], QUuid::createUuid().toString());
        mDatabasePool.setLocalData(database);
        return database;
    }
}
```

So the database connection will only created when the thread does not has the connection.

For full sample project you can check on my project :https://github.com/apinprastya/sultan. The database is inside the libdb and the worker QFuture is in libserver. You can use it as reference. But I am not sure if my design is suitable for you.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I checked your sample and code in your github, now I'm trying to understand the scheme: So, I have many threads which should use DB. I should to use `QFuture` with `QtConcurrent::run` for method `executeQuery()` in `DatabaseService` class if I need to execute a query from these threads. Next, `executeQuery()` will call `DatabaseService::getDatabase()` method, which exactly the same as your, for getting `QSqlDatabase` instance and then `executeQuery()` will execute query using obtained `QSqlDatabase` instance. Where am I wrong?

Comment: yes, you are right. With QFuture you don't need to take care of the live cycle of thread. The QFuture will use thread pool from QThreadPool::globalInstance(). You can increase the number of thread pool by set the setMaxThreadCount() on the global thread pool.
You will also need a QFutureWatcher as handler when the QFuture done with the task and send signal to main thread data you query from DB.

Comment: Thanks, please check the code which I posted in the **UPD** section of my question, is it all correct(except absence of `QFutureWatcher`, because I want to call `executeQuery` and get result of it in the same function)?

Comment: If you already has separate thread who call executeQuery, using QFuture will be useless. It will be thread create another thread. And are your thread is a pool or you create a new thread when calling executeQuery?

Comment: >"It will be thread create another thread" Yes, I thought about the same. Can you clarify your last question?

Comment: So when you call the executeQuery -> this actually a separated thread, right? How do you create this thread? When you call executeQuery, do you create a new thread for that?

Comment: Yes, right. I create this thread using `QtConcurrent::run`, and I already understood that it's wrong. So, I have three questions: **1.** Now I should to call `executeQuery` in the same thread, instead of calling `QtConcurrent::run`, because I already have separated thread, correct? **2.** But is it ok, if I will have the same number of `QSqlDatabase` instances as number of these threads? **3.** I have so many threads because I create a thread for each client connection. So, maybe I can improve this architecture too?

Comment: 1). yes you are right. 2). QSqlDatabase is a session to your database, on mysql there is a max connection setting on the server, just make sure the number of QSqlDatabase is not exceed the max connection. 3). For me better to use thread pool here rather than create a new thread every client connection. But I am not sure what are you working on, are you working on http rest server? means that 1 request per client connection.

Comment: I think it will be better if you share your current implementation on your question to better understand your current design.

Comment: No, I'm working on SSL via TCP server. I found this design pattern [here](https://forum.qt.io/post/349002), please check `kshegunov`'s comment, it refers to [this repo](https://bitbucket.org/nye/qtdaemon/src/f8c744b54a6a/examples/daemon/tcpserver/?at=master). I attached my simplified code in the **UPD 2** section in the my question, you can check it. And, as always, thanks!

Comment: Ah so you are working on TCP socket, it mostly similar to mine (i use websocket, but the websocket not support multi thread). Something to consider with your current implementation is when you are using your thread and execute a heavy sql query, it will block your thread.

Comment: Ok, I understood. Everything else is ok with DB connection pool and this scheme of connecting new clients?